# How to style a Google Map under Codename One API?

Tags: google-maps, codenameone, styling

I use a map in my CN1 application. For inject the map in my form, i use this type :

```
MapContainer mapContainer = new MapContainer();
```

My app must run only on an IPad tab. I can view my Google map correctly. But i need to style this map. With Javascript i can do this :

```
var styles = [
    {
        featureType: "administrative.country",
        elementType: "labels",
        stylers: [ { color: '#f24547' } ]
    }
];

map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: navigationData.googlePosition,
    zoom: 15 
});
map.setOptions( { styles: styles } );
```

How can i do the same in my CN1 java code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the styles of native Google Map like that in Codename One but you can set the map type, zoom level, center position and current location.

```
MapContainer mapContainer = new MapContainer();
mapContainer.setMapType(MapContainer.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
mapContainer.setShowMyLocation(true);
LocationManager lm = LocationManager.getLocationManager();
Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation();
if (lm.isGPSDetectionSupported()) {
    if (lm.isGPSEnabled()) {
        Location loc2 = lm.getCurrentLocationSync(20000);
        if (loc2 != null) {
            loc = loc2;
        }
    } else {
        Dialog.show("", "MyAppName needs access to your current location, please enable GPS in Settings.", "Ok", null);
    }
} else {
    Location loc2 = lm.getCurrentLocationSync(20000);
    if (loc2 != null) {
        loc = loc2;
    }
}
mapContainer.zoom(new Coord(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude()), 15);
```

Comment: For completeness I'd also mention that you can fork the [Google Maps Codename One port](https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-google-maps/) and do style changes there